# Supply an image thumbnail with my RSS feed

Tags: html, xml, rss

I want the images in my RSS feed to be displayed so that if the feed is taken into Facebook my page will show the image with it.

This is my RSS feed:

```
<item>
<title>Title</title>
<link>www.website.com</link>
<guid>www.website.com/1/</guid>
<description>Description</description>
</item>
```

Do I add `<image></image>` and just stick the URL in? Or should I use `<media:thumbnail>`?

I don't want the image to be the main content but instead have it show as thumbnail preview like when sharing a webpage on Facebook.

Comment: So if the RSS feed is taken into FB on my page it will show the image with it.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_tag_image.asp is a description

Comment: What do you guys think of <media:thumbnail> I found that?

Comment: <media:thumbnail> is supposed to include the link to a thumbnail image for another media file, not being the media itself. But if you find it useful for your purposes it might work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<image> 
              <title>Hello World</title> 
              <url>imageurl.gif</url> 
              <link>http://sitelink</link> 
 </image>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about <media:thumbnail> I dont want the image to be the main content, i want the content to have a image with it like on facebook it would show the thumbnail as the image.

Answer (score 3):

To include an image in your RSS, you have two options on how to markup the item.

1. Convert the `img` tags to escaped HTML entities:

   ```
    <description>&lt;img src="http://example.com/path/to/image"&gt;</description>
   ```
2. Wrap the description content within a CDATA section:

   ```
    <description><![CDATA[<img src="http://example.com/path/to/image">]]></description>
   ```

If you're thinking of using the `<media:thumbnail>` field, it's more for showcasing a [thumbnail representation](http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss#media-thumbnails) of an object enclosed in `<media:content>`.

> This element allows you publish a thumbnail image of your image or video. For Media RSS aware readers, this is a key feature, since readers are more likely to click on your media content if it has a nice shiny thumbnail. You’ll definitely need to give the URL attribute of your thumbnail image, which is all you basically need to do in order to include a thumbnail image.
>
> **[Use Media RSS](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/use_media_rss/)** - Webmonkey

Comment: Can i have an iamge and description in my description?

Comment: Your description can have all sorts of HTML normally seen on a webpage. Some readers may not parse things like video embeds though @son

Answer (score 1):

use `<enclosure>` tag

e.g:

```
<enclosure 
  url="https://my.domain.tld/images/my_picture.jpg" 
  type="image/jpeg" 
  length="1967"
/>
```

see w3c documentation : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/rss_tag_enclosure.asp

Comment: That's not the W3C website.

Answer (score 0):

`<image>` won't work inside `<item>` in RSS 2.0, only inside of `<channel>`. The accepted solution here is nonfunctional.

Comment: Please add link to official docs to prove that!

Comment: https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt and https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#ltimagegtSubelementOfLtchannelgt ... <image> is NOT an element of <item>. It's an element of <channel> only.